# Why does the toString method in java not seem to work for an array

Tags: java, tostring, arrays

I want to convert a character array to a string object using the toString() method in java. Here is a snippet of the test code I used:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
class toString{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        char[] Array = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'};
        System.out.println(Array.toString());
        }
}
```

In principle, it should print **abcdef**, but it is printing random gibberish of the likes of **[C@6e1408** or **[C@e53108** each time the program executes. I don't need an alternative out of this but want to know why this is happening.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

To get a human-readable `toString()`, you must use [`Arrays.toString()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString%28double%5B%5D%29), like this:

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(Array));
```

Java's `toString()` for an array is to print `[`, followed by a character representing the type of the array's elements (in your case `C` for `char`), followed by `@` then the "identity hash code" of the array (think of it like you would a "memory address").

This sad state of affairs is generally considered as a "mistake" with java.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7284322/256196) for a list of other "mistakes".

Comment: Thank you Bohemian. can you also tell me the meaning or the context of the gibberish that is being printed otherwise.

Comment: @sidharth: It's not "gibberish" - see my answer for where it comes from.

Comment: Just upvoted this, over a year later as a similar issue hit me and I found this post - really surprised ```toString()``` wasn't overridden for an object dealing with human readable characters!

Comment: You didn't actually explain how to get "abcdef" as OP requested.

Comment: @Bohemian or anyone, is there a reason why it can't be/hasn't been re-implemented as part of a language change?

Comment: It isn't a mistake. Java arrays are special classes with zero builtin methods beyond what's directly inherited from Object and a single special field which isn't even handled like ordinary fields. In order to have Array.toString() to print what you seem to expect it would need to be overloaded on the Array class which is a non-starter.

Comment: @ShmuelNewmark IMHO it is a mistake that the array class provides a sensible toString. There is nothing whatsoever stopping the array class from being given such an upgrade: Just call `Arrays.toString(this)`.

Comment: @Bohemian But there is no real Array class. It's all written in C to be directly handled by the JVM. You could still put the logic in there, but then you're overriding a method in secret without a clear class inheritance structure. Someone calling that method would have to dig a lot just to find the actual logic being invoked.

Comment: What’s funny about this discussion, is that the even simpler `System.out.println(Array);` does the intended thing.

Answer (score 38):

I don't know where you get the idea that "in principle" it should print "abcdef". Where is that documented?

Something like `[C@6e1408` is certainly *not* random gibberish - it's the same way of constructing a string from an object as any other type that doesn't override `toString()` inherits - it's a representation of the type (`[` indicating an array; `C` indicating the `char` primitive type) followed by the identity hash code in hex. See the [documentation for `Object.toString()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString%28%29) for details. As it happens, arrays don't override `toString`.

If you want `[a, b, c, d, e, f]` you can use [`Arrays.toString(char[])`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString%28char%5B%5D%29). If you want `abcdef` you can use `new String(char[])`.

Comment: I think *'in principle'* it is expected to overwrite the ```toString()``` method as it deals with characters and human-readable content which could be outputted to a valid human-readable string. Or at the very least implement something like the ```Arrays``` class, as you point out. From the first sentence of the documentation (as I skimmed it) I only saw **Returns a String object representing this Character's value.** which I expected to mean it overrides ```toString()``` + outputs a String object with a length of one; a human readable representation. Obviously my bad for skimming; but still!

Comment: @FergusMorrow: That's the documentation for `Character.toString`. This isn't a single `char`, it's an *array*. Basically, you should only rely on `toString` doing anything particularly useful for classes where it's been overridden, and it isn't overridden for arrays. That's certainly a shame, but the OP had no good reason to expect anything different "in principle" IMO.

Comment: Actually, it is the purpose of the hash to be _random_.

Comment: @avidD: No, the purpose of a hash isn't to be *random*. It's to be different between different objects, as far as possible. It doesn't matter whether it's unpredictable or not - that's not the point.

Comment: @JonSkeet has the correct answer. You should accept it as such.

Comment: If you want `abcdef` you can just use `System.out.println(Array);`…

Comment: @Holger: That doesn't solve "I want to convert a character array to a string object" though. Yes, it prints "abcdef" to the console, but that's not really the point of the question.

Comment: If you think you have to take this literally, the OP said “*I want to convert a character array to a string object **using the toString()** method*”, so your variants `Arrays.toString(char[])` and `new String(char[])` are not matching that sentence either. In fact, the question’s last sentence is “*I don't need an alternative out of this but want to know why this is happening.*”, so any suggestion how to fix it is outside the scope of the question. Or we agree on addendums beyond the literal question being allowed. For most real life tasks, you don’t need to convert a `char[]` to a `String`…

Comment: @Holger: I think we'll have to agree to disagree on whether just `System.out.println(Array);` would have been a useful answer. I'm not sure why you've even thought it work commenting on an answer that's nearly 11 years old, explains what's happening *and* how to get a more useful string reputation. You can continue to do so, but I'm not going to waste any more time on this.

Comment: This old Q&A has been linked in newer Q&As, e.g. by closing other questions as duplicates. That’s how I got here. It wasn’t my intention to spend more thoughts beyond the original single line comment; it was you, who started a discussion about what the OP intended a decade ago. My comment might not be useful to the OP but perhaps to the other readers who get redirected here.

Answer (score 2):

Arrays don't override `toString`. There's a static method: `java.util.Arrays.toString` that should solve your problem.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
class toString {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        char[] Array = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'};
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(Array));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use the following commands to get your abcdef array printed

```
    String a= new String(Array);

    System.out.println(a);
```

there you have it  problem solved !!
now regarding why is printing the other stuff  i think those guys above put  some useful links for  that.
Ok gotta go !!

Answer (score 1):

Because a char array is an array of primitives and toString() will give you it's default (which is a hash of the object). Some classes will implement toString() to do cooler things, but primitaves will not.

Comment: "a char array is a primitive" You mean an array of primitives, surely.

Answer (score 0):

The default implementation of the toString method of the char [] class returns a String representation of the base address of the array, which is what is being printed here. We cannot change it, since the class of char [] is not extendable.

Answer (score 0):

There is a spelling mistake of "Array.toString()" to "Arrays.toString(Array)" I guess so, and instead of writing name.toString(), pass the name as an argument and Write as above.

Answer (score -1):

```
char[] Array = { 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f' };
System.out.println(Array);
```

It should print `abcdef`.

Comment: This is correct but this doesn't quite fit the question. OP wants to convert the `char[]` to a `String`, and not just print it. He just used the print statement as a "debug"-option to show the output of `.toString()`.

Comment: @ImpulseTheFox there is no prove to your claim that the “OP wants to convert the char[] to a String, and not just print it”. In fact, the OP said explicitly “*I don't need an alternative out of this but want to know why this is happening.*” so the OP wanted neither, know how to print it nor know how to create a string.

Answer (score -3):

this way I found worked:

```
public String convertToString(char[] array, int length)
{
String char_string;
String return_string="";
int i;

   for(i=0;i<length;i++)
   {
       char_string=Character.toString(array[i]);
       return_string=return_string.concat(char_string);
   }
   return return_string;
}
```

Comment: He is not asking for an alternative, he is asking for an explanation of the behavior.