# Generating a series of numbers

Tags: mysql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Generating a series of dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14105018/generating-a-series-of-dates)

What is the best way in mysql to generate a series of numbers in a given range?

The application I have in mind is to write a report query that returns a row for every number, regardless of whether there is any data to report. An example in its simplest form might be:

```
SELECT numbers.num, COUNT(answers.id)
FROM <series of numbers between X and Y> numbers
     LEFT JOIN answers ON answers.selection_number = numbers.num
GROUP BY 1
```

I have tried creating a table with lots of numbers, but that seems like a poor workaround.

Comment: unclear exactly what you want. will a sequence work?

Comment: Seems like the same as How do I get a list of numbers in MySQL? to which I got the answer that there's no good way to do this.

Comment: "Where did you get this cool hat?" The answer is hatwhoring.

Comment: @Bohemian :) I saw one with generating dates earlier... So if you are posting again here on similar lines, then there has to be something more interesting underneath.

Comment: @JanDvorak Visit this chat room I set up for this purpose: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6904/stackoverflow-new-years-eve-hat right now and I'll fix you up

Comment: @bonCodigo I believe the term being used is "hat whoring" :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, create a table called ints which will contain one record for each digit from 0 to 9.

```
CREATE TABLE ints ( i tinyint );
```

Then populate that table with data.

```
INSERT INTO ints VALUES (0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9);
```

Now you can use a query such as the following to generate a sequence of numbers.

```
SELECT generator.num, COUNT(answers.id)
FROM (
    SELECT a.i*10 + b.i AS num
    FROM ints a, ints b
    ORDER BY 1
) generator
LEFT JOIN answers ON answers.selection_number = generator.num
WHERE generator.num BETWEEN 18 AND 43
```

To add another place value to the generated numbers, just add more joins of the ints table and adjust the calculations accordingly.  The following will generate three-digit numbers:

```
SELECT generator.num, COUNT(answers.id)
FROM (
    SELECT a.i*100 + b.i*10 + c.i AS num
    FROM ints a, ints b, ints c
    ORDER BY 1
) generator
LEFT JOIN answers ON answers.selection_number = generator.num
WHERE generator.num BETWEEN 328 AND 643
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try with group by numbers.num instead of group by 1

```
SELECT numbers.num, COUNT(answers.id)
FROM numbers
     LEFT JOIN answers ON answers.selection_number = numbers.num
WHERE numbers.num between X and Y
GROUP BY numbers.num
```

Comment: But what is "numbers"? That's the question

Comment: i am also confused. but i guess it might be table name containing a column named num