# SQL COUNT(*) return 0 IFNULL with WHERE clauses and GROUP_BY on same table

Tags: mysql, sql, count, sql-order-by, ifnull

The result should return a row with the date even if the count is `null`.

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(created_date, '%Y-%m') AS date, COUNT(*) AS total
FROM mytable
WHERE created_date BETWEEN :startDate AND :endDate 
AND condition = :condition
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(created_date, '%Y-%m')
ORDER BY created_date ASC
```

I saw that i should use `LEFT JOIN` and `IFNULL`, but I tried with no good result.

Desired result :

```
array(1) {
  [0]=> {
    ["date"]=>
    string(7) "2016-01"
    ["total"]=>
    string(1) "0"
  }
  [1]=> {
    ["date"]=>
    string(7) "2016-02"
    ["total"]=>
    string(4) "9492"
  }
  [2]=> {
    ["date"]=>
    string(7) "2016-03"
    ["total"]=>
    string(1) "0"
  }
}
```

PS : I'm using MySQL

Comment: Which `DBMS` you are using. Tired of writing this statement :/

Comment: When you say the result should return a row, is that the expected or desired result?

Comment: @Prdp Sorry, edited

Comment: @mchev - Actually you should tag. I have did it for you. Keep this in mind for future questions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`LEFT JOIN` is correct but with what table you did `Left join`. You need a `calendar` table with List dates

You dont have to use `IFNULL` when there is no records found for a particular `date` then `Count` aggregate will return `0`

```
SELECT Date_format(c.dates, '%Y-%m') AS date,
       Count(m.created_date)         AS total
FROM   Calendar_table c
       LEFT JOIN mytable m
              ON c.dates = Cast(m.created_date AS DATE)
WHERE  created_date BETWEEN :startDate AND :endDate
       AND condition = :condition
GROUP  BY Date_format(c.dates, '%Y-%m')
ORDER  BY c.dates ASC
```

For creating `calendar` table he is an article : [Calendar Tables: An Invaluable Database Tool](http://www.brianshowalter.com/calendar_tables)

Comment: For this case, i don't have a calendar table and can't create it.

Comment: @mchev - Check this question there is an option to generate dates with creating a table http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14105018/generating-a-series-of-dates

Comment: That's mean i should create a table and destroy it on every query?I think i'll take the php option to check dates who are not in the result.

Comment: @mchev - No, You can create a permanent table with list of dates whats wrong in that. That table will be very useful for reports

Comment: Ok, i'll check if i need this calendar for other parts. I don't want to create a big calendar table (need to go far far in time) for only one query. Thanks ;)

Comment: @mchev - There are options to generate dates without creating table. Check the answer I shared in previous comment. Am not a expert in `Mysql` else will share a example in my answer

Comment: Sure it's just one query now, but a calendar table is super helpful in a lot of queries.