# Generate time serie between time interval with steps of minutes on the fly in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, time, query-optimization, recursive-query

The question is in the end of this post.

I found this link to generate date
[Generating a series of dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14105018/generating-a-series-of-dates)
and modified it to generate time in an intervall:

```
SET @start_time = "08:02";
SET @stop_time  = "17:02";
```

```
SELECT
     TIME_FORMAT(time(CONCAT(m3, m2, ':', m1, m0)) , "%H:%i") as Time
FROM
    (SELECT 0 m0 UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) AS m0,
    (SELECT 0 m1 UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6) AS m1,
    (SELECT 0 m2 UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4) AS m2,
    (SELECT 0 m3 UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2) AS m3
where time(CONCAT(m3, m2, ':', m1, m0)) is not null 
and time(CONCAT(m3, m2, ':', m1, m0)) >= @start_time
and time(CONCAT(m3, m2, ':', m1, m0)) <= @stop_time
order by Time asc
```

This will generate this table:

```
Time
10:02
10:03
10:04
10:05
10:06
...
16:59
17:00
17:01
```

## Question?

Can this be written in a more effective way? I should like to specify an interval with steps, so can quickly update it to every X minute intervall instead. I don't want to store the result in DB, i just want to generate it on the fly. Since I will join it with other tables.

I use this a lot in mysql queries to make time serie for measurements that are easy to plot in Excel.

Comment: I personally think there is a reasonable argument for storing it in the DB, as a table with 1440 rows, a time column, possibly with an hour column and minute column too then you can do eg `SELECT * FROM times WHERE MOD(minute, 5) = 0` (or `MOD(MINUTE(time), 5)` if no separated minutes column) to get eg "every 5 minutes, times ending with 0 / 5". Databases are really good at querying tables; they do a lot of it..

Comment: I only have a read only account, and my time series is often very short with maybe only usually under an hour. I made it longer in this example so the solution should be more generic.

Comment: You'll have to go some reasonable distance to find a DBA that would advocate generating X rows on the fly Y times a day over having a small amount of rows in a table and selecting them, I think.. The read only restriction is a bigger stick than the low number of rows is a carrot

Comment: Adding a lot of temporary tables will pollute the database. Thats why they started with the read only account, since most of the users where bad at cleaning up after them self.

Comment: This isn't a temporary table, it's a permanent one; ask the next 10 DBA you come across what they think about calendar and numbers tables. They're probably more widespread than you think and they make a lot of sense, especially calendar tables, as they can tell you things that formulaic generation of date series can't, such as public holidays

Comment: Easy to do with a sequence table on the fly in MariaDB.

Comment: Meanwhile, I second Caisus's permanent table.  It could even have a million _integers_ and use integer and/or date arithmetic to create all the minutes in an arbitrary range (up to 1M).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm a fan of recursive CTEs for this purpose:

```
with recursive times as (
      select time('10:00:00') as time
      union all
      select time + interval 17 minute
      from times
      where time < time('17:00:00')
     )
select *
from times;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=fb99b1c82def50ef945952b617db71cf) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Is it definitely available in the OP's MySQL?

Comment: Thanks, this was much simpler than my solution.

Comment: @banankontakt . . . The place to start is with the documentation on recursive CTEs:  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/with.html#common-table-expressions-recursive.