# Get query result of every month between two dates

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, date-range

create table link : https://drive.google.com/file/d/1EEqpW2Y8UkplfQcp_fw0j2byXAxBQXOW/view?usp=sharing

I have a query

```
SELECT 
    DATE_FORMAT(seized_date,'%Y-%m') as 'Seized Date',
    sum(case when seized_remarks = 'Temporary Seized' then 1 else 0 end) AS seized,
    sum(case when (DATE_FORMAT(release_date, '%Y-%m') BETWEEN '2021-01' AND '2021-07') then 1 else 0 end) AS released,
    sum(case when (DATE_FORMAT(stock_return_date, '%Y-%m') BETWEEN '2021-01' AND '2021-07') then 1 else 0 end) AS stock_return
FROM mahindra
where 
(DATE_FORMAT(seized_date, '%Y-%m') BETWEEN '2021-01' AND '2021-07')
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(seized_date,'%Y-%m')
```

which gives result as

```
Date    Seized  Release Stock Return
2021-01    1      0         0
2021-03    1      0         0
2021-04    1      0         0
2021-05    5      1         0
2021-06    6      0         1
2021-07    2      0         0
```

here i didn't get the result of february 2021. I want to get the result of all months between this two dates even if the seized_date does not exist

Comment: If the table does not contain any data for any year/month then you myust generate dynamically a table which cintains all year-month combinations for needed period and leftjoin your data table to it.

Comment: As Akina said, you will need to create a calendar table, as shown in this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14105018/generating-a-series-of-dates

Comment: *Link to my table(mahindra)* Convert your CSV to CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO scripts. Remove unnesessary columns and data. Show desired output for this data.

Comment: here is the link to create table https://drive.google.com/file/d/1EEqpW2Y8UkplfQcp_fw0j2byXAxBQXOW/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1):

As @Akina says, if the `seized_date` value does not exist anywhere in your table, you cannot expect it to be present in your results at all.
You need to create a column containing all required dates and then you can do something like perform a join onto that column.

Here's an example of how I might do it.

```
 SELECT  TO_CHAR(DATEADD('MONTH', -n, (CURRENT_DATE+1)),'YYYY-MM') AS seized_date
   FROM (
        SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER () AS n 
        FROM mahindra LIMIT 10
        ) 
   ORDER BY seized_date DESC
```

This is creates the following output.

[image]

**Code explanation:**

The inner query is based on a window function.
The window function itself is simple. We're basically telling the computer to assign a value of 10 to `n`. To a human, "10" is a numeric value assigned to a specific thing or count of things (eg the temperature is 10 degrees, or I have 10 apples), but to the processor/computer, it doesn't mean much on its own. At least not in our scenario. So we simply tell the processor to count some rows `ROW_NUMBER` and when it finds 10 rows, that's what 10 looks like. You can use `LIMIT` to make this greater or fewer than 10 months.

In the outer query we just take today's date `CURRENT_DATE` and subtract `n` months from it as in `(DATEADD('MONTH', -n, (CURRENT_DATE+1)`.
In our case, `n` is 10 months.

Now you have a column of dates, formatted as you per your requirements `YYYY-MM`.

You can write the query such that you `LEFT JOIN` your precessed data set to these dates on their corresponding values.

The reason why this is a good way of doing things is that you don't have to manually enter any dates or use a `UNION` join. You let the window function do the work for you, meaning you can go back in time as far as you need/or want very easily by changing the `LIMIT` value. This allows for greater efficiency in the event where you need to go back over multiple years, for example.

Comment: @Tanvir Nabil
Did either of these answers help you achieve your end goal?
If so please select one, it helps the community.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need in something like

```sql
SELECT 
    dates.`Seized Date`,
    COALESCE(SUM(mahindra.seized_remarks = 'Temporary Seized'), 0) AS seized,
    COALESCE(COUNT(mahindra.release_date), 0) AS released,
    COALESCE(COUNT(mahindra.stock_return_date), 0) AS stock_return
FROM ( SELECT '2021-01' `Seized Date` UNION ALL
       SELECT '2021-02' UNION ALL
       SELECT '2021-03' UNION ALL
       SELECT '2021-04' UNION ALL
       SELECT '2021-05' UNION ALL
       SELECT '2021-06' UNION ALL
       SELECT '2021-07' ) dates
LEFT JOIN mahindra ON DATE_FORMAT(mahindra.seized_date, '%Y-%m') = dates.`Seized Date`
GROUP BY dates.`Seized Date`
```

Comment: `COUNT()` never returns `NULL`, so `COALESCE()` is unnecessary.

Comment: @GordonLinoff True. Simply I add COALESCE firstly, and replace SUM with COUNT() later...