# How to query MySQL database for each day in a date range?

Tags: sql, mysql, mysql-5.7

I have these three tables:

| hotel |
| --- |
| hotel_id |
| hotel_name |

| room |
| --- |
| room_id |
| hotel_id |

| room_price |
| --- |
| room_id |
| date |
| price |

I know how to query the database to get the price for a given room_id and given date for the hotel stay. So I can do it, however, when it comes to doing this for a long date range, this becomes impractical.

Comment: Its nice that you added some sample output you desire ... but I'm not understanding the "Missing" data where you just add dots to the tables. (such as  a row that just says `... ... ...` - can you make this more complete. Also, why are the dates not actually dates and why are the prices not actually prices (numbers)? Finally, what are you really trying to do? You say *So I can do it, however, when it comes to doing this for 14+ night stays, this becomes impractical* ... but why is that impractical? Nor do I see what this has to do with your output - which is not prices for a "14+ night stay".

Comment: Your output table appears to be a result for every room for every date (forever?) Is that really what you want? Or is it rather prices a particular room, for a single date range?

Comment: @topsail There is check_in date and check_out date which are fixed. I would like to see prices for each room between these specific dates I.E. check_in, check_in + 1 day , …, check_out

Comment: You know as of last month 5.7 no longer gets security updates, right? And that 8.0 can handle this particular class of problem waaay faster and easier?

Comment: Also, to solve these we need to know about the table holding checkin/checkout dates for each visit. Also, customers don't like it when a room price changes mid-stay, and hotels commonly give customers the price based on the first day of the visit for the entire visit. Is something like that going on here?

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn I only need to query for one pair of check_in date, check_out date. E.g. I define these using SET, then hopefully I can query for the desired output table

Comment: @Amarillo45 Well, the "no security update" thing is a **big deal**. You may need to solve this issue for 5.7, but converting to 8.0 or later needs be **job #1** before doing anything else afterwards.

Comment: It's not the official requirements, but you can run 8.0 on a Core 2 Duo from 2012.

Comment: *"calculate total prices for a given room instead of having to do each day individually"* - so the `price` changes based on  the `room_price`? you might need a [date series](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45992255/4648586). unfortunately i cant fork out a working query for you. its kind of odd that `any_value()` on mysql5.7 and mysql8 behave differently even with `primary key` configured.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could either create your date series dynamically, as shown in the [answer suggested by Bagus Tesa](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45992255), or maintain a calendar table. Given that dates play a big part in booking/reservations apps, I would suggest creating a simple calendar table.

For this example I am using a calendar table with just a single dt (`DATE`) column, which you can easily populate with a stored proc (or any other method you choose):

```sql
CREATE TABLE calendar (dt DATE NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY);

DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE `filldates`(dateStart DATE, dateEnd DATE)
BEGIN
  WHILE dateStart <= dateEnd DO
    INSERT INTO calendar (dt) VALUES (dateStart);
    SET dateStart = dateStart + INTERVAL 1 DAY;
  END WHILE;
END$$
DELIMITER ;

CALL filldates('2023-01-01', '2039-12-31');
```

Then it is a simple case of a `CROSS JOIN` between the dates for the booking and rooms, and a correlated subquery to retrieve the price per room per day:

```sql
SET @checkin = '2023-11-26', @checkout = '2023-12-15';

SELECT r.room_id, COUNT(*) AS nights, (
    SELECT price
    FROM room_price
    WHERE room_id = r.room_id
    AND start_date <= c.dt
    ORDER BY start_date DESC
    LIMIT 1
) AS price
FROM calendar c
CROSS JOIN room r
WHERE c.dt >= @checkin AND c.dt < @checkout
GROUP BY room_id, price;
```

Note: although the keyword `CROSS` has no significance in MySQL (it's just an INNER join with no ON clause), I think it makes the intent clear.

Here's a [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/U851XM7N).

Comment: Please provide an updated fiddle with your actual query that is failing, as the example I gave you clearly works.

Comment: Thanks I did not see the fiddle. I will try again

Comment: Hello, I have just tested this query and it works fine. How could you add a fallback? If a date is not available as in the room_price take the price from a standart_table...
Thank you