# Properties File Not Stored In Correct Order

Tags: java, properties

I'm saving several values in a properties file, yet whenever I open the file, the values are not written in the order that I coded.

```
save.setProperty("SN", "foo");
save.setProperty("ID", "bar");
save.setProperty("TN", "example");
save.setProperty("TC", "generic");
save.setProperty("SW", "incorrect");
save.setProperty("NW", "order");
save.store(new FileOutputStream(file.getAbsolutePath(), null);
```

This is how the file looks when I open it:

```
#Sat Jul 13 19:28:59 EDT 2013
ID=bar
SW=incorrect
TC=generic
TN=example
NW=order
SN=foo
```

As you can see, the order is completely off from the coding. I am curious as to why this happens. It is obviously not sorted alphabetically, and I can't see any other reason why it should happen like this.

Comment: You will also notice that comments get moved or removed as well.

Comment: @HotLicks Because I was curious. Why do _you_ care?

Comment: Because if you have a dependency on the order you probably have a conceptual problem with your design.

Comment: @HotLicks I said I was _curious_, didn't I? I don't think I ever said I have a dependency on the order.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [`Properties`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html) class extends the [`Hashtable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Hashtable.html) class.

The iteration order of a hash-based set is undefined.

---

Incidentally, the fact that `Properties` *extends* `Hashtable`, instead of *using* Hashtable, is considered one of the many design "mistakes" in the JDK.

For a brief list of other "mistakes", see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7284322/256196).

Answer (score 1):

There's a good chance that the properties system is using a backing `HashMap` of some description. This is so that you can set the same property many times over and it will update the current value. To do this efficiently, a `HashMap` is required. Because of this, the order is entirely up to the implementation of the `HashMap` (It's not guaranteed to be alphabetical)

Comment: There's more than a 'good chance'. Properties extends Hashtable.

Comment: I wasn't 100% certain, I've never used `Properties` before. It was just a guess that turned out to be right!