# How to add days to date using java

Tags: java

DateUtil.addDays(days, date) is there any addDays method in java to add days to a date?
Provide me any solution for this that how to add days to date

Comment: How exactly did this extremely poor question got 5 upvotes, even when originally mistagged with [java-ee] tag?

Answer (score 2):

JDK native date/time handling is pretty poor. The [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/quickstart.html) library's `DateTime` is better than `java.util.Date` class for anything requiring manipulation:

```
DateTime dt = new DateTime();
DateTime twoDaysLater = dt.plusDays(2);
```

If you want to create a `DateTime` from a `java.util.Date`:

```
Date nativeDate = new Date();
DateTime dt = new DateTime(nativeDate);
```

If you need to convert back to a `java.util.Date`:

```
Date date = dt.toDate();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use calendar.

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
c.setTime(new Date()); // Now use today date.
c.add(Calendar.DATE, 5); // Adding 5 days
String output = sdf.format(c.getTime());
System.out.println(output);
```

Answer (score 2):

The closest thing in the JDK is using [`TimeUnit`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/TimeUnit.html):

```
date.setTime(date.getTime() + TimeUnit.DAYS.toMillis(days));
```

---

It is interesting to note that (quite unbelievably) [`Date`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) is not [*immutable*](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object)! Just one of many [questionable design decisions in the JDK](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7284322/256196).