# Convert byte array to String

Tags: java, blackberry, java-me

How do I convert a byte array to a String in BlackBerry?

I have used

```
new String(bytearray,encoding type);
```

I am getting `[B@fb5955d6` when calling toString().Can anyone help get this string in a readable format for BlackBerry?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6684665/java-byte-array-to-string-to-byte-array

Comment: **How** are you seeing the value `[B@fb5955d6` for your byte array?  Are you looking at it in the debugger?  Printing it out?  Please show some of the code you have tried to use.  If you tried `new String(byte[], encoding), *which* encoding did you use?

Answer (score 2):

You don't show us **where** this byte data is coming from, or **what** value you expect it to have.  So, I'm not sure I can *fully* debug your problem.  But, hopefully this helps:

The reason you are seeing `[B@fb5955d6` printed out when you simply call `toString()` on your byte array is that the [default implementation of toString()](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/6.0.0api/java/lang/Object.html#toString%28%29) will just [print out a short code for the array data type](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7060025/119114) (e.g. `byte`), and then something like an *address* (if you're familiar with C/C++) of your variable, which is almost never what you really want, especially in Java.

When you have binary data (as a `byte[]`), Java doesn't know whether you intend that data to be a `String`, or a `ButtonField`, or a `FuzzyWarble`.  So, it has nothing more meaningful to print out than the object's address.

If you want to print out `String` data, you need to create a `String` object with the `byte[]`, but to do that, you need to either use the default [character encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encoding), or specify which encoding you want.  `"UTF-8"` and `"ASCII"` are two popular encodings.

If I run this code

```java
  try {         
     byte[] bytes = new byte[] { 100, 67, 126, 35, 53, 42, 56, 126, 122 };
     System.out.println("bytes are " + bytes.toString());
     String s = new String(bytes, "UTF-8");
     System.out.println("string is " + s);
  } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e1) {
  }
```

I see this

> bytes are [B@3b50e2ee 
>   string is dC~#5*8~z

As you see, the *address* I see is different from the one you see (because I'm running on a different machine, with different memory layout).  But, when converted to a `String` with `"UTF-8"` encoding, I see the value that you see.

So, maybe that's the right value?

Again, we don't know where the binary data comes from, or what it's supposed to be, but I can tell you that the code above is a typical way to convert byte arrays to strings.

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
byte[] byteArray = new byte[] {87, 79, 87, 46, 46, 46};

String value = new String(byteArray);
```

This will give you the value 'WOW..'