# can't assign random number to array

Tags: java, arrays

So i am having problems with my code here. What I am basically trying to do is assigning a value to each BC[0] and adding 1 to BC01[0] and 2 to BC02[0] doing that for each boat.
(trying to make battleships (advanced))

but all i am able to print out is

```
[[I@7852e922
```

Anyways, here is my code

```
public class dogs {
    public static int BC00 [] = {0,0};
    public static int BC01 [] = {BC00[0],BC00[1]};
    public static int BC02 [] = {BC00[0],BC00[1]};
    public static int boat0[][] = {BC00, BC01, BC02}; //location cells boat[0][0]
    public static int BC10 [] = {BC01[0], BC01[1]};
    public static int BC11 [] = {BC01[0], BC01[1]};
    public static int BC12 [] = {BC01[0], BC01[1]};
    public static int boat1 [][] = {BC10, BC11, BC12};
    public static int BC20 [] = {BC02[0], BC02[1]};
    public static int BC21 [] = {BC02[0], BC02[1]};
    public static int BC22 [] = {BC02[0], BC02[1]};
    public static int boat2 [][] = {BC20, BC21, BC22};
    public int NH; // Number of hits
    public static int allBoats [][][] = {boat0, boat1, boat2};
    public static int rand;
    public static int n = 0;
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        for (int x = 0; x <= 2; x++) {
            Random gen = new Random();

            rand = gen.nextInt(6) + 1;
            allBoats[x][0][0] = (int) rand;
            while(n <= 2) { //give boatCells locations

                allBoats[n][1][1] = allBoats[n][1][1] + 1;
                allBoats[n][2][1] = allBoats[n][2][1] + 2;
                n++;
            } // end of while loop
        } // end of For loop
        System.out.println(boat0);
    } // end of public static void main(String[] args)
} // end of dogs class
```

Comment: You should probably tag this with the specific programming language you are using.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does the toString method in java not seem to work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7060016/why-does-the-tostring-method-in-java-not-seem-to-work)

Comment: take a look at [Java Variables Naming Conventions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/variables.html)

Comment: Since `n` is a static field, the first iteration of your for loop is the only one where your `while` will be entered. Also, you don't need to keep re-instantiating Random (and in fact that's a really **bad** idea). You don't need a temporary int (or a cast) for gen.nextInt() either.

Comment: tostring() is not for creating "user friendly" output (as mentioned in the answer below).  But I have some other comments for your code:

All you variables are pulic (that is bad in cases of data-encapsulation)

You write Comments at the end of all blocks (this is also bad (in my opinion), because this comments will become wrong if you forget to change one vblock)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(boat0));
```

instead of

```
System.out.println(boat0);
```

And as @ChristianKuetbach has suggested, it is important to understand that in Java, `toString()`-Mothod often does not mean "A mothod to generate a user-readable String". Most classes prints ClassName@HashCode.

Comment: You should explain, that in Java a toString()--Mothod does not mean "A mothod to generate a user-readable String". The most classes prints ClassName@HasCode.