# Method to take in values for parameterized constructor

Tags: java, input, constructor

I'm running into a problem here.  I was told to initialize values through a parameterized constructor. Write a method "getInput" to take in values for these attributes, call the parameterized constructor and then return a Child object.

I think this is what I did...but when I call the method i get something like this: Child@75d9fd51
Is this just the object reference?  I'm trying to get it to print the inputted age, name and grade.
Thank you in advance!

So far this is what i have:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Child{
    int age;
    String name;
    char grade;

public Child(){

}

public Child(int age, String name, char grade) {
    this.age = age;
    this.name = name;
    this.grade = grade;
}
public int getAge() {
    return age;
}
public void setAgel(int age) {
    this.age = age;
}
public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
public char getGrade() {
    return grade;
}
public void setGrade(char grade) {
    this.grade = grade;
}
}

public class Data {

public static Child getInput(Child s){
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Input age: ");
    int age = input.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Input name: ");
    String name = input.next();
    System.out.println("Input grade: ");
    char grade = input.next().charAt(0);
    s = new Child(age, name, grade);

    return s;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub


    Child x = new Child(20, "James", 'A');   //I want this to be changed with input

    getInput(x);

    System.out.print(x);
}
```

Comment: Child x = getInput(20, "James", 'A');

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use the toString method in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3615721/how-to-use-the-tostring-method-in-java)

Comment: 1. Read up `System.out.println(Object)`. Notice it invokes `Object.toString()`. 2. ??? 3. Profit.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does the toString method in java not seem to work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7060016/why-does-the-tostring-method-in-java-not-seem-to-work)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, 'Child@75d9fd51' is not a object reference. It's the data stored in the instance x of the class Child. In the Java programming language, every class provides a hashCode() method, which digests the data stored in an instance of the class into a single hash value (a 32-bit signed integer).

If you want to get the input data and print the inputted data(age, name and grade), you should make some changes:

First, change `getInput(x);` to `x = getInput(x);`. This statement assigns new class to the class x.

Second, put the method

```
public String toString() { 
   return "Input age: " + getAge() + "\nInput name: " + getName() + "\nInput grade: " +        getGrade(); 
}
```

inside child class. When you call `System.out.print(x);` on main method, `System.out.print(x.toString());` is actually called.

Comment: No problem. How you want me to change the post format?

Answer (score 2):

Override your `toString` methode in your child class

```
public String toString(){
        return age + " " + name + " " + grade;
    }
```

when your run this line in your agent class which is Data

```
public static void main(String...args){
   Child x = new Child(20, "James", 'A');   
   System.out.print(x.toString());
  }
```

output:

```
Input age: 
32
Input name: 
izak
Input grade: 
A
32 izak A
```

Answer (score 1):

A generic `Object` doesn't have a specific printable representation just because Java can't just guess how you'd like to print it. So what you obtain is the reference in memory.

But the language gives you the `public String toString()` method from `Object` class, which can be overridden to provide the specific representation you'd like. This method is automatically called when you pass an object to the `println` method.

Eg:

```
class Child {
  public String toString() { 
       return name + "," + grade + "," + age;
  }
}
```

Comment: Oh! That's so useful!  So now all I have to do to get it to implement my new inputs is use my setters to take in the inputs?

Answer (score 1):

When passed an object, `System.out.println()` will print out the results of the object's `toString` method. The default output is in the format you're seeing. If you want to see something more informative, you can either pass the fields individually

```
System.out.println("Age: " + x.getAge());
System.out.println("Name: " + x.getName());
System.out.println("Grade: " + x.getGrade());
```

or you can override the `toString` method on `Child`:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Age: " + this.age + ", Name: " + this.name + ", Grade: " + this.grade;
}
```

Now you can call `System.out.println(x)` as you were before.

On a side note, there's no point in creating and passing an instance of `Child` just to replace it with a new instance in `getInput`.

Comment: Thank you!  Out of curiosity why is there no point in doing that? Also I was trying to use the method it to implement my new inputs.  So if I set those inputs to my setters it might work?

Comment: @user3806226 I'm not sure why you would think there's a point. You're creating an instance of a class and ignoring it.

Comment: @user3806226 I'm not sure I fully understand your question, but if you want to add fields to your `Child` class, they would also have to be specified in your output.

Comment: Sorry, I'm a beginner so I'm not really sure about everything yet.  I figured out my problem, though, sorry for the confusion!  Thanks for the help!