# Why DataFrame.collect() not returning array

Tags: scala, dataframe, hadoop

I am trying to call collect() over a Dataframe in Scala 2.12. Instead of returning an Array[Row], it returns me this - [Long.apache.spark.sql.Row;@58131fc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's annoying, but on the JVM, in both Java and Scala, that's just how the `toString` method on arrays works. Instead of seeing the contents, you get a cryptic thing beginning with e.g. `[L`:

```
scala 2.12.10> Array("foo").toString
res0: String = [Ljava.lang.String;@8bffb8b
```

So it appears to me that you do in fact have an `Array[Row]`.

See also [Why does the toString method in java not seem to work for an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7060016/why-does-the-tostring-method-in-java-not-seem-to-work-for-an-array)